# How to remove dead BMVerts from a list?

Tags: python, bmesh

I am trying to fix a bug in my script that happens in rare instances. I believe the bug occurs due to the very last thing the script is doing, which is:

```
bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=verts_to_weld, dist=0.001)
```

I think the problem is that **verts_to_weld** refers to a list of BMVerts that contains dead elements. This is because earlier in the script I use bmesh.ops.delete() to get rid of inner faces after using bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(). So essentially my Remove Doubles is referring to some vertices that have been deleted earlier and don't exist in my bmesh anymore, but are still in the list. Is there a way to take the list **verts_to_weld** and remove any dead verts from that list? Thanks! Here's what my error looks like and also the print(verts_to_weld) at the bottom:

[image: Error and printed list of verts_to_weld]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look at the `is_valid` property of a bmesh element.**

In this case you have verts in your list that are no longer valid. Use [`BMVert.is_valid`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVert.is_valid) to check.

Try

```
bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, 
        verts=[v for v in verts_to_weld if v.is_valid],
        dist=0.001)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the print output, it looks like the 'dead' vertices don't have any index associated with them. Did you try iterating through the list -  verts_to_weld -  and removing vertices with `index == None`? Or maybe print the index of all the vertices in the list and see what it is for dead vertices. Most likely it won't be an int.

Comment: Very, very  unlikely an int property is no longer an int. See the documentation  [BMVert.index](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVert.index)  Dead bmesh elements are marked as invalid eg `is_dead = not vert.is_valid`

Comment: @batFinger I tried checking the is_valid flag of the deleted verts. But they had it set to True. That's the reason I thought it could be determined through the index. Maybe I missed something while making the delete call.

Comment: The v.is_valid works perfectly for me.

Comment: @z01ks Glad to know that :)